# How to decode base64 image in python running on Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to decode a base64 string to an image object in python in google app engine. i

```
imported Image from PIL 
from PIL import Image
```

and try to decode like this

```
image = Image.fromString('RGBA', (iWidth, iHeight), decodeString(imageEncodedString))
```

i get error saying `type object 'Image' has no attribute 'fromString'`

So how do i get around doing this :
send a base64 image to google app engine as request. Decode it on server. Do some transformations and encode it back to base64 and return as response.

**Edit**

As mentioned in comments first issue was a typo and second was that iWidth and iHeight were interpreted as string. so i changed my code to

```
image = Image.fromstring('RGB', (int(iWidth), int(iHeight)), decodestring(imageEncodedString))
```

But now i get the error

> ValueError: not enough image data

Here is my base64 encoded image

> 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

Comment: the function is fromstring, with a lowercase 's'.

Comment: I fixed it. But now i got his traceback.
File "/base/data/home/apps/uniengine.py", line 257, in post
    image = Image.fromstring('RGB', (iWidth, iHeight), decodestring(imageEncodedString))
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/PIL-1.1.7/PIL/Image.py", line 1796, in fromstring
    im = new(mode, size)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/PIL-1.1.7/PIL/Image.py", line 1763, in new
    return Image()._new(core.fill(mode, size, color))
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: Are `iWidth, iHeight` actually integers?  I urge you to edit your Q to improve formatting and include the content of this comment formatted in a readable way, plus display those variables...

Comment: No the weren't. i edited my code and also my question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
from PIL import Image
from cStringIO import StringIO
from base64 import decodestring

decoded_img_str = base64.decodestring(imageEncodedString)
imgfile = StringIO(decoded_img_str)
image = Image.open(imgfile)
```